# How to enable Auto Scaling for Provisioned read capacity in DynamoDB from java script

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js

I am using AWS SDK for nodejs and creating a dynamodb table from the code. It all works fine but i need auto scaling to be enabled for provisioned read and write capacity. This is the code i am trying

```
var params = {
    TableName : "MyTable",
    KeySchema: [       
        { AttributeName: "Name", KeyType: "HASH"},  //Partition key
        { AttributeName: "time", KeyType: "RANGE" }  //Sort key
    ],
    AttributeDefinitions: [     

        { AttributeName: "Name", AttributeType: "S" },
        { AttributeName: "time", AttributeType: "N" }
    ],
    ProvisionedThroughput: {       
        ReadCapacityUnits: 5, 
        WriteCapacityUnits: 5
    }        
    ]
};

dynamodb.createTable(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to create table. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    } else {
        console.log("Created table. Table description JSON:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
    }
});
```

This creates a table with read and write capacity as 5 but with auto scaling disabled. I have seen a java sample where auto scaling is being handled from code but nothing for java script. Any suggestions on how to enable auto scaling from NodeJS will be very helpful . 
Thanks

Comment: You can configure the auto scaling to be handled at database table side itself from AWS management console.

Comment: Yeah i realize that, but thats not what i am looking for. It has to be done from code level as we are exposing some api's to clients and they will not have console access.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I followed jens walters solution and the UI for dynamodb looked broken--from overview it said scaling was enabled but when I viewed the capacity tab it didn't show that it was.  This is because that solution is missing the second half--scaling policy.

The solution is a 2 step process:

1. Register the scalable target
2. Put the scaling policy in place on the target

Here's the code:

```
var tableName = "your-table-name"

var autoscalingParams = {
   MaxCapacity: 15,
   MinCapacity: 1,
   ResourceId: "table/" + tableName,
   RoleARN: "arn:aws:iam::" + accountId + ":role/current-lambdaRole",
   ScalableDimension: "dynamodb:table:WriteCapacityUnits",
   ServiceNamespace: "dynamodb"
};

autoscaling.registerScalableTarget(autoscalingParams, function(err, data) {
   if(err) {
       console.log('error');
       console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
   } else {
       console.log(data);
   }

   var scalingPolicy = {
       ServiceNamespace: "dynamodb",
       ResourceId: "table/" + tableName,
       ScalableDimension: "dynamodb:table:WriteCapacityUnits",
       PolicyName: tableName + "-scaling-policy",
       PolicyType: "TargetTrackingScaling",
       TargetTrackingScalingPolicyConfiguration: {
           PredefinedMetricSpecification: {
               PredefinedMetricType: "DynamoDBWriteCapacityUtilization"
           },
           ScaleOutCooldown: 60,
           ScaleInCooldown: 60,
           TargetValue: 70.0
       }
   };

   autoscaling.putScalingPolicy(scalingPolicy, function(err, data) {
       if(err) {
           console.log('error');
           console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
       } else {
           console.log('success!');
           console.log(data);
       }
       cb(err);
   });
});
```

Then your role will need permissions something along the lines of:

```
{
  "IamPolicyLambdaManageScalingDynamoDbTables": {
    "Type": "AWS::IAM::Policy",
    "Properties": {
      "PolicyName": "someName",
      "PolicyDocument": {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
          {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
              "application-autoscaling:RegisterScalableTarget",
              "application-autoscaling:PutScalingPolicy",
              "iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole",
              "iam:PassRole"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
          }
        ]
      },
      "Roles": [
        {
          "Ref": "IamRoleLambdaExecution"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

*Note:  You should probably not use the wildcard for the role resource, but I haven't nailed down what those should be exactly*

Comment: I get an error on registerScalableTarget : "DynamoDB table does not exist:<table name>" on a known existing table
Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You can enable the auto-scaling through a separate ApplicationAutoScaling call.

Here a Lambda code sample of how to enable auto-scaling for write units:

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
var applicationautoscaling = new AWS.ApplicationAutoScaling({
    apiVersion: '2016-02-06'
});

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    var params = {
        MaxCapacity: 10,
        MinCapacity: 2,
        ResourceId: "table/MyTable",
        RoleARN: "arn:aws:iam::111111111:role/lambda_s3_exec_role",
        ScalableDimension: "dynamodb:table:WriteCapacityUnits",
        ServiceNamespace: "dynamodb"
    };
    applicationautoscaling.registerScalableTarget(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
        else console.log(data); // successful response
        callback(null, 'write capacity adjusted');
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks , i will try it out today. Btw if i mention readcapacityUnits along with write in scalableDimension then both read and write can be set as scalable right?

Comment: Yes, both can be set, but as far as I understood the API, they have to be set with two separate calls.

Comment: well i tried it and i get an error " not found" . but table does exists in dynamodb.

Comment: i have created an ARN with correct roles and if i use that with CLI it works fine , however on using it with the above code. I get not found error 404.

Comment: The only reasons I could come up with is, that the dynamodb is running in a separate region or that the table is not yet fully available. AWS says, that the DB has to be active, to activate the autoscaling. So you might need to check the state of the table before activating the autoscale feature.

Comment: yeah i am checking for table to be active. i use dynamodb.waitFor('tableExists', params, function(err, data) . I also tested this with an existing table but same error.

Comment: I did run the above code within a Lambda function and cannot produce any 404 error. So far I only got qualified errors from the SDK like PermissionDenied or ValidationException (table does not exist).

Comment: Well i am running this code from a node js service not from lambda.. ofcourse with my RoleARN. Strange thing is if i try the commandline which takes exactly same arguments as shown above then it works ..

Comment: I was getting the Not Found error as well until I changed the AWS.ApplicationAutoScaling configuration to use an endpoint with "autoscaling", e.g. var autoscaleClient = new AWS.ApplicationAutoScaling({ apiVersion: '2016-02-06', region: "us-east-1", endpoint: "https ://autoscaling.us-east-1.amazonaws.com" }); (space in URL to prevent StackOverflow from formatting as a hyperlink).

Comment: What permissions should role 'arn:aws:iam::111111111:role/lambda_s3_exec_role' have?